# writing content from a pdf file in a text field

Tags: python-3.x, linux, list, tkinter

I need to insert the content of a pdf file inside a listbox following the codes below:

```
from tkinter import *
from textract import process

master = Tk()

scrollbar = Scrollbar(master)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
ficheiro="./livro/instrucoespdf.pdf"
listbox = Listbox(master, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text=process(ficheiro)
data=text.decode('utf8')
listbox.insert(END, data)

listbox.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox.yview)

mainloop()
```

To decode de text inside of that pdf file I chose "textract" library. I print the content to the terminal everything comes real cool, however, when I put that in a listbox the content will be all in the same line which is undesirable. 
Any idea how to solve this issue?

when I use "textract" to print to the terminal:
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSYBR.png)

when I put in the listbox:

[in the gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AqnQ.png)

Comment: What exactly means  "when I print the content to the terminal everything comes real cool". What is the value of `data`. Maybe you have to put it into `listbox` line by line?

Comment: when I refer "When I print to the terminal comes real cool" insted of using a GUI to see the output I use the print() and that prints with breaklines that thing doesn't append using a GUI because the brea lines desapear and the content will be all in the same line I don't know how to put the content line by line. The var data will have all the words from that pdf file when I decode I remove all the '\n' for example

Comment: Please add all information to the question. Please show the (example) data instead of describing how it looks.

Comment: Try to help me now :) thanks

Comment: Try changing `listbox.insert(END, data)` to `listbox.insert(END, *data.split())`.